# Is it possible to define a numba jitclass of a recursive data type

Tags: numba, recursive-datastructures

I'd like to speed up my python code of a simple implementation of a tree-like data structure. The first thing that comes to mind is to jit it with numba. The problem I'm running into is how to tell numba the types of `Node` as one of its members is of type `Node` again. Here's a minimal example:

```
spec=[("value", nb.float64), ("parent", Node.class_type.instance_type)]
@nb.jitclass(spec)
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value:float, parent:"Node") -> None:
        self.value:float = value
        self.parent:Node = parent
```

This example obviously doesn't work since when defining `spec` it doesn't know what to do with the class `Node` yet.

Is this even possible in numba?

Comment: It is not supported yet, but you can use the deferred_type to achieve what you want.    You can see an example by following the link in the discussion at https://numba.discourse.group/t/recursive-python-type-annotations-in-jitclass/537